# How to CLONE/COPY a TFS 2012 Collection to another instance of TFS 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008, tfs, clone

Is there a way to copy/clone a TFS Collection in our TFS 2012 production environment to a fresh install of TFS 2012 in our test domain?

I have tried using SQL Management Studio to do backup/restore which does not work.

I have tried using TFS Backup and Restore Wizard which does not recognize the bak file either.

It seems like the only kind of Collection you can attach or restore to TFS 2012 is a collection that came from that exact instance?

This is rather silly. I was expecting to be able to simply use a SQL Management studio and this would be clean and simple.  Been here for a while now and ... not so much!

I have tried with the TFS Backup and Restore Wizard as well... the tool only seems to recognize Collections from it's own instance.

Quite frustrating.  I am starting to think Collections aren't as portable as one might think at first.

Answer (score 0):

You will need

1. detach the collection through the TFS Administration Console
2. back up the database through SSMS and restore it to your new TFS's SQL instance.
3. re-attach the original collection to your production TFS instance
4. attach the copied database to your new TFS instance

This does mean that your Prod TFS Collection will be unavailable while you are detached, but the detach and re-attach generally does not take much time depending on the size of your database.